# How do you pull beans related by foreign keys in RedBeanPHP?

Tags: mysql, orm, php-5.3

I'm using RedBean PHP ORM 1.2 with Zend and Mysql for a new project. I'm still in the process of learning it and it works very well for many scenarios, except i cant find how to load beans related by foreign keys. Allow me to explain.

I have two tables; members and feeds. Each 'feed' is linked via a foreign key (in MySQL) to a member. The schema (of sorts) is like this :

```
Member table:
 ID - Primary Key
 NAME - A text field

Feeds Table:
 ID - Primary Key
 COMMENT - A text field
 USER_ID - This is linked via a MySQL FK to Member.ID
```

What i would like to do is something like :

```
 $feed = $rb->load('feeds',1);
 $feed->member->NAME //this should get me the name of the member using the FK
```

But i cant see how i can do this. I have read about links, associations and trees but none of those work for the scenario where data already exists in the table and i just need to pull a bean and another bean thats related. For clarification, here is the code that does what i want :

```
$feed = $rb->load('feeds',1);
$member = $rb->load('members',$feed->USER_ID);
$member->NAME //This works
```

I'd really like to avoid that extra line, and more importantly having to redeclare that FK on the App level.

Your comments and thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

RedBean is an ORM that favours code over schema definitions. Although you can use RedBean with a prefined schema it really works best if you just treat it like an object database.

```
R::setup();

class Model_Feed extends RedBean_SimpleModel  {
  public function getMember() {
    $member = R::relatedOne($this->bean,"member");
    return $member;
  }
}
```

To test this:

```
//test....
$feed = R::dispense("feed");
$feed->comment = "lorem ipsum";
$id = R::store($feed);
$member = R::dispense("member");
$member->name = "Xavier";
R::clearRelations($feed,"member",$member);
$feed = R::load("feed",$id);
echo $feed->getMember()->name; //prints: Xavier
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, var_dump($feed->getMember()->name); leads to a null value...